# 404 ao setar um app.route no Flask

Tags: python, flask

Tenho esse simples código disponível na página do Flask:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Ao subir o Serviço, tudo funciona perfeitamente.
Porêm, ao adicionar algo no `app.rote`, vai retornar um 404. 
Ex: `app.route("/Teste")`

Porque isso acontece ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto:

```
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

Gera uma rota *default* na instância do seu site. Quando você muda para:

```
@app.route("/Teste")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

A rota *default* não existirá mais, e haverá uma outra rota chamada `/Teste`.

O recomendado para seu teste seria você definir duas ações com rotas diferentes:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

@app.route("/Teste")
def teste():
    return "Oi! Isto é um teste."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Com isso, tanto `/` quanto `/Teste` funcionam.

Comment: Entendi. Fiz o teste e funcionou 100%. valeu.